# Azure Storage Table partition key and row key performance consideration for more unique values

Tags: performance, azure, azure-table-storage

I am creating a record in Azure Storage Table and using latitude and longitude as partition key and row key respectively.

Are there any performance degradation since there is very little chance that there will be same lat and lon values?

What is the effect on query performance if I store lat and lon in a separate column and not row and partition key?

**Note:**
To query the records I will be using less than or greater than operators of oData

Comment: When you plan on querying the data, what types of queries will you be doing? Will you always have latitude when you are looking something up?  Knowing how you plan accessing the data would go a long way in helping answer if this is a good approach or not.

Comment: I will be using range queries such as greater than or less than operators using oData.

Answer (score 0):

Row and partition keys are more concerned with the efficient performance of your queries, I.e if you are querying the table using Row and Partition key combined both of them would serve the purpose of indexing with great speed of data retrieval. So make your decision such that you can optimize your performance